# Google org chart missing links

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

This jsfiddle contains a google org chart that represents a family tree for Mike, whose parents Jim & Alice are also brother and sister. [this is a simplification of a real world problem].

The org chart is not displaying the parents of Alice.  How can I force the full tree to be represented?

```
        data.addRows([
      ['Mike', ''],
      ['Jim', 'Mike'],
      ['Alice', 'Mike'],

      ['Bob', 'Alice'],
      ['Carol', 'Alice'],

      ['Bob', 'Jim'],
      ['Carol', 'Jim']

    ]);



http://jsfiddle.net/simon831/36gg3ro1/55/
```

Answer (score 0):

Your column names need to be unique. I updated your [fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/q66s1a3o/)

```
['Mike', ''],
['Jim', 'Mike'],
['Alice', 'Mike'],

['Bob', 'Jim'],
['Carol', 'Jim'],

['Bob2', 'Alice'],
['Carol2', 'Alice']
```

From the data property description of google org charts:

> Column 0 - The node ID. It should be unique among all nodes

[googlechart api documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart)

Comment: But now it looks like Bob and Bob2 are 2 different people, so the family tree is wrong.

Comment: but the parent-child relationship is valid. You simply have to treat your parent nodes as one unit. So if Alice and Jim had Bob and Carol, Alice and Jim are a single parental unit. Your structure implies that there are two Bobs and two Carols which isn't a real-world scenario. Consider having your node like `['Jim & Alice'] -> ['Bob'], ['Carol']`